# Script or command to list all top-level directories that contain sub-directories with modified files less than 30 days old

Tags: scripting, find

This is quite a unique one.

I'm looking for a way to list all top-level directories in a folder that contain sub-directories with new or modified files less than 30 days old in them.

We use a replication method to sync user files to a central repository and I'm looking for a way to monitor which users have synced files within the last month.  We can then troubleshoot the ones that are not.

I've used "find . -type d -mtime -30"  but this lists every sub-folder and the output is too big to provide a concise picture.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What operating system are you on? Do you have GNU `find`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `find` on each directory in turn, and pipe it to `grep -q .` to check if there are *any* results, and print the directory name conditionally upon whether or not there were any results:

```
for d in */; do find "$d" -type f -mtime -30 | grep -q . && printf %s\\n "$d"; done
```

Comment: Thank you both so much for your replies.  This worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

This might be not efficient:

```
find -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type f -mtime -30 | 
    xargs -n 1 dirname | 
    xargs -n 1 dirname | 
    uniq # (or sort -u, I assume find's output is already sorted)
```

Comment: +1.  but use `-print0` with `find`, `-0` with `xargs` AND `-z` with both `dirname` and `uniq`/`sort -u` (requires a recent-ish version of GNU coreutils)....otherwise this will break on any file/dir name containing spaces/newlines/etc.   BTW, `find`'s output isn't sorted, so use `sort -z -u`.  Finally, pipe the output through `tr '\000' '\n'`.  Resulting in `find -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type f -mtime -60 -print0 | xargs -0r -n 1 dirname -z | xargs -0r -n 1 dirname -z | sort -z -u | tr '\000' '\n'`

Answer (score 0):

```
find */ -type f -mtime -30 -print0 | 
    sed -z -e  's:/.*$::' | 
    sort -z -u | 
    tr '\000' '\n'
```

Requires GNU `sort` and GNU `sed` for the `-z` (NUL-separated input) options.

`find` lists all files in subdirectories of the current directory less than 30 days old.  output is piped into `sed` to remove everything after the first `/`, then into `sort` to unique sort the resulting directory names.